# Disaggregating multiring polygon for editing, then recombining?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-flex-api

We have many rows of multi-ring polygons, displayed on a Flex front end.  We need to be able to select a polygon (a row), split the rings for editing, edit them, then combine into one polygon again.  I thought we could mulipart to single part, but that requires a whole FC and copies it to a new FC; whereas we want to be able to split, edit then recombine.

I have built a spatial toolset class in Python and am now building the tools for this.  But, I must admit, I am struggling to conceive how to do it.

I also have another approach, which would be to select the id of the ring associated with the polygon; i.e., the polygon will have 1..n rings.  I don't know the Flex API well, but I am sure you must be able to select the ring id of the polygon and `removeRing()`?

I am using ArcSDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS 10 you can use just the Geometry object in most all ToolBox commands that accept a FC.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001z000000

I would try this:

select a multipolygon,
capture the geometry in a geometry object,
explode to single part,
edit a part(s),
recombine parts,
update the geometry of the original multipart polygon

Comment: This was what I planned.  However, when exploding to multipart, you do so to another Featureclass, not the one you're working on.